# How to create a dialog box in WIX UI?

Tags: wix, installation

I am trying to create a custom dialog box using Wix. The issue arises due to the fact I have the company logo overlayed in the background and it becomes somewhat difficult to read the opening introductory text. Thus I want to create a white text box that would allow the dialog to stand out from the company logo without having to revert to the bland white background. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not adjusting the graphics file that you use as background (the company logo, as you said) and add the white overlay to this graphic and use this as background?

Comment: Thats a good idea however it tends to look a little funny as I kind of want/need a white overlay that adapts to the amount of dialogue the installer displays

Comment: I admit it would be tedious, but you could add a different background for every dialog, using different sizes of the white overlay. But as said, it would be tedious, involving the customizing of every dialog.